# Command or UI to see what is in the CrudRepository

Tags: android, eclipse, spring, server

Is there any command to execute or UI to see what is stored in my CrudRepository? I am creating a server using Spring which you can add pre-existing users or data into the database when running the server. Client (Android mobile) can also add or update the data of the repository.

Something similar to that of the client side like this:
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/01/23/working-with-sqlite-databases-through-command-line-in-android/

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-rest-service-oauth</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.7.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: What database are you using? Many databases have tools to visualize/access/edit the stored data.

Comment: @Darkean CrudRepository in Spring Data JPA

Comment: Yes, but which DATABASE? MySQL? Postgre? A Spring Data repository is backed by a database. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you are probably using a default in-memory database such as H2. It would be helpful if you provided the dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Added answer using the information from the `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your `pom.xml` you are using HSQLDB which is an embedded database that is most likely running in-memory, started and managed automatically by your Spring Boot app.

You can visualize the content of the database using the **HSQL Database Manager** GUI.

See here for a HOW-TO guide: [View content of HSQLDB embedded database](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-view-content-of-hsqldb-embedded-database/)